# Post JSON to Azure website

Tags: c#, azure

I have a string that uses JsonTextWriter to create a JSON formatted-string. How do I interact with it if I want to store it in an Azure website? I was thinking of using an httpWebRequest like

```
 string webAddr = "http://{url to website}/test.json";
 HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
 httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
 httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"; 

 StringWriter strwriter = new StringWriter();
 JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(strwriter);
 writer.WriteStartObject();
 writer.WritePropertyName("id");
 writer.WriteValue(v.id);
 writer.WriteEndObject();

 using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = strwriter.ToString();

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to actually post the JSON to a file. Am I missing anything?

I think that it would be fine to store on the local storage of the VM/website to avoid a CORS issue, unless there is something that Blob storage would benefit over local storage.

Comment: Are you unclear about the server side? Or do you have that figured out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're part way there, next you need to actually dispatch the request:

```
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

And you can read through the returned body (if required):

```
using (httpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

    string response_body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Assuming you just wanted to dump the body to the file system (for arguments sake):

```
using (httpWebResponse)
{
    ...

    using (var file = new FileStream("some\path\to\file.json",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None))
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file,Encoding.UTF8);

        writer.Write(response_body);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

However this won't work for non VM websites, for that you'd probably have to shun the file off to blob storage.